# Memory leak in Delphi XE3 when error happens on inserting into sqlite db

Tags: delphi, sqlite

```
...
Query: TSQLQuery
...
    Query.SQL.Clear;
    Query.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO pumps'#13#10 +
                       'VALUES (NULL, :title, :power)');
    Query.ParamByName('title').AsString:= title;
    Query.ParamByName('power').AsFloat:= power;
    try
      Query.ExecSQL;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        begin
          ShowMessage(E.Message);
        end;
    end;
```

Query is linked to SQLConnection with driver=Sqlite. All the operations do work, but when I try to insert a non-unique value into the column with unique index, I get exception about value existance. OK, my code catches it and shows a message 'column title is not unique', but before debugger shows me that exception TWICE. When I close program, memory manager tells about memory leaks, and that leaks are:

- 21 - 28 bytes: UnicodeString x 4
- 61 - 68 bytes: TDBXSqliteCommand x2
- 69 - 76 bytes: TDBXMorphicCommand x 2
- 221 - 236 bytes: Unknown x 2

Is it possible to avoid that?

UPD: I used FastMM4 to get detailed log, and below is a part about one memory leak:

```
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 68

This block was allocated by thread 0xB18, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
4068A6 [System.pas][System][@GetMem$qqri][4203]
4082BB [System.pas][System][TObject.NewInstance$qqrv][14969]
4089D2 [System.pas][System][@ClassCreate$qqrpvzc][16231]
7D5A91 [Data.DbxSqlite.pas][Data.DbxSqlite][Dbxsqlite.TDBXSqliteCommand.$bctr$qqrp26Data.Dbxcommon.TDBXContextp35Data.Dbxsqlite.TDBXSqliteConnection][567]
6E3DFE [Data.DBXCommon][Generics.Collections.%TDictionary__2$20System.UnicodeStringp32Data.Dbxcommon.TDBXCreateCommand%.GetBucketIndex$qqrx20System.UnicodeStringi]
7D4C8E [Data.DbxSqlite.pas][Data.DbxSqlite][Dbxsqlite.TDBXSqliteDriver.CreateSqliteCommand$qqrp26Data.Dbxcommon.TDBXContextp29Data.Dbxcommon.TDBXConnectionp26Data.Dbxcommon.TDBXCommand][295]
6CE4DA [Data.DBXCommon.pas][Data.DBXCommon][Dbxcommon.TDBXDriver.CreateMorphCommand$qqrp26Data.Dbxcommon.TDBXContextp29Data.Dbxcommon.TDBXConnectionp26Data.Dbxcommon.TDBXCommand][7569]
6D5177 [Data.DBXCommon.pas][Data.DBXCommon][Dbxcommon.TDBXDelegateDriver.CreateMorphCommand$qqrp26Data.Dbxcommon.TDBXContextp29Data.Dbxcommon.TDBXConnectionp26Data.Dbxcommon.TDBXCommand][11061]
6D09F4 [Data.DBXCommon.pas][Data.DBXCommon][Dbxcommon.TDBXConnection.CreateMorphCommand$qqrp26Data.Dbxcommon.TDBXCommand][8480]
6D1C21 [Data.DBXCommon.pas][Data.DBXCommon][Dbxcommon.TDBXMorphicCommand.DerivedOpen$qqrv][9084]
6D1974 [Data.DBXCommon.pas][Data.DBXCommon][Dbxcommon.TDBXCommand.Open$qqrv][8962]

The block is currently used for an object of class: TDBXSqliteCommand
```

Comment: Can we assume that when a unique value is posted there's no leak?

Comment: Do you have the leak when you run the program outside the debugger? I always have UnicodeString leaks when debugging code...

Comment: Doesn't the memory manager also tell you *where* those leaked things were allocated?

Comment: Use the full version of FastMM and get some real diagnostics. This will tell you where each leaked block was allocated, and give you the call stack at the allocation point. Without that information we are all helpless.

Comment: To pile up on what @whosrdaddy said, see my blog post ["when The Debugger Leaks..."](http://fgaillard.com/2011/02/when-the-debugger-leaks/).

Comment: ...and also heed @DavidHeffernan's advice.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz, yes, when record is stored correctly, and database returned no error, I get no leaks.

Comment: @whosrdaddy, yes, running program outside the debugger causes error to appear, too.

Comment: @François, I've read your post and succesfully tried to do given example about UnicodeString leaks. But, in my situation, I think,  UnicodeStrings is not the main issue. It is more interesting about TDBXSqliteCommand and TDBXMorphicCommand, which is not created by myself, but somewhere in DBX Sqlite driver or somewhat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run tests with dbXpress **SQLite** and **MySQL** driver (XE3) and your code just leaks with SQLite (also get the double exception in debug mode) but it **doesn't with MySQL**.

IMHO this is a bug that should be reported to QC.

Stack Trace at **first exception occurrence** in debugger

```
:769cc41f KERNELBASE.RaiseException + 0x58
Data.DBXCommon.TDBXContext.Error(???,'column title is not unique')
Data.DbxSqlite.CheckError(19,???,$2F12738)
Data.DbxSqlite.TDBXSqliteCommand.DerivedExecuteQuery
Data.DBXCommon.TDBXCommand.ExecuteQuery
Data.DBXCommon.TDBXMorphicCommand.ExecuteQuery
Data.SqlExpr.TCustomSQLDataSet.ExecuteStatement
Data.SqlExpr.TCustomSQLDataSet.ExecSQL(???)
Data.SqlExpr.TSQLQuery.ExecSQL(???)
Main_ViewU.TForm1.RunQuery($2E7B870,'Title',10)
Main_ViewU.TForm1.Button1Click($2E85AD0)
```

Stack Trace at **second exception occurrence** in debugger

```
:769cc41f KERNELBASE.RaiseException + 0x58    // <-- Exception interrupts Destroy
Data.DBXCommon.TDBXContext.Error(???,'column title is not unique')
Data.DbxSqlite.CheckError(19,???,$2F12738)
Data.DbxSqlite.TDBXSqliteCommand.DerivedClose
Data.DBXCommon.TDBXCommand.Close
Data.DBXCommon.TDBXMorphicCommand.DerivedClose
Data.DBXCommon.TDBXCommand.Close
Data.DBXCommon.TDBXCommand.Destroy            // <-- DESTROY
Data.DBXCommon.TDBXMorphicCommand.Destroy     // <-- DESTROY
System.TObject.Free
Data.SqlExpr.TCustomSQLDataSet.CloseStatement
Data.SqlExpr.TCustomSQLDataSet.InternalFreeCommand
Data.SqlExpr.TCustomSQLDataSet.FreeCommand
Data.SqlExpr.TCustomSQLDataSet.ExecSQL(???)
Data.SqlExpr.TSQLQuery.ExecSQL(???)
Main_ViewU.TForm1.RunQuery($2E7B870,'Title',10)
Main_ViewU.TForm1.Button1Click($2E85AD0)
```

And that causes the Memory Leak ...

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I understand about try ... finally, but I gave a code to show that error appears exactly during executing ExecSQL, and only in case of database error (in my situation this error is duplicate value on unique index). To be accurate, TSQLQuery is a component inside DataModule, but, repeat, if database responce has no errors, I get no memory leaks.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this research. As I understand my assumption about buggy code inside DBX was right, didn't it? :). And, unfortunately, I have no possibility to report about bug to QC.

Comment: Of course you can report a bug to QC. Anyone can do that. If you care about the tools you use, you should be part of the effort to make it better.